# Can't get the input that I want to

Tags: c, function, input

I just started C programming and I'm a newbie. I did some research but unfortunately couldn't find anything about my problem. Can't use array BTW that's why i don't use it.

So, I'm making a function to print stars as many as given number. But function is printing the last input number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    void pstr(int *m){
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < *m; j++)
            printf("*");
            printf("\n");
    }

    int i;
    int number = 9;
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9;

    printf("Enter 9 numbers (all less than 50):\n|1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9|\n");   
    printf("|-----------------|\n ");        
    for(i=0; i < number; i++)                                           
        scanf("%d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5, &n6, &n7, &n8, &n9);

    pstr(&n1);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I'm trying to print the first input number, but It's writing the last one(n9). Sorry about my English, Thank you.

Comment: I surprised that  this compiled since in C a function cannot be buried within another function.  I.E. move the pstr function to before the line int main(void) <-- be sure to include the 'void'

Answer (score 3):

Your `scanf()` format string is wrong.

```
scanf("%d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5, &n6, &n7, &n8, &n9);
```

You must have one `%` *for each conversion*, so 9 in your case. That would mean that the `for` is pointless.

Also, you must check that `scanf()` returns the expected number of successful conversions, otherwise you can't depend on the variables having proper values.

Comment: Thank you but when i add 8 more %s, it prints the second input minus 1.

Comment: @HalilM ,Umm,shouldn't `%s` be `%d` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
 scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d ", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5, &n6, &n7, &n8, &n9);
```

Though better way would be to use an array and a loop. Since you are a novice I don't think you know about it yet. Use this for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Declare numbers as:

```
int n[9];
```

instead of

```
int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9;
```

Then use the loop as:

```
for(i=0; i < number; i++)                                           
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);
```

Also, before using scanf, fflush the output buffer,

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: OP said "Can't use array BTW that's why i don't use it."